# What is difference between -Dwtpversion and wtpversion?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp

I am new to Maven. I am going to develop my first application in with Maven. So while reading the documentation I found `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0`

I know [WTP](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools) is the "Web Tools platform", but what is `-Dwtpversion`? I searched on the Internet, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "-D" prefix in the argument means that it's a *system property*.

A system property is defined like this in(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html#SYS):

> A system property is a key/value pair that the Java runtime defines to
>   describe the user, system environment, and Java system. The runtime
>   defines and uses a set of default system properties. Other properties
>   can be made available to a Java program via the -D command line option
>   to the Java interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 makes it a maven project that can be run from eclipse